# Multiple SSIS projects getting data from same table at the same time

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have two projects, 
 i) Loading  - Writing only selected columns  to a CSV output from table A
 ii) Archive - Writing all the fields  (as a part of archiving) from the same  table A (as above)

Inside each  project, I have only 1 packag with 17 dataflow tasks (each dft is getting data from 17 diff tables to write this data into 17 diff CSV files).

Even thought, I'm currently running both these projects simultaneously and the projects take a lot of time (approx 2-3 days) to finish. Since, these two projects are getting the data from the same data sources, I'm not sure if the table is getting locked (I even tried doing a no-lock on sql scripts in data source).

I'm concerned if there was any better way to make this happen without taking so much time.

Please help me.

Thanks,
Atulya

Comment: It's taking 2-3 days to export a bunch of tables. That seems excessive. It might have nothing to do with the database and could instead be that the disks on the writing side are slow. I suggest you use `sp_whoisactive` to observe locks and waits while this is running. It might be wating due to I/O or it might be waiting due to contention.

Comment: Also, `BCP.EXE` can be a much simpler solution to extracting data. What is the purpose of the CSV files? Are you sending data to other systems or doing a manual backup?

Comment: Hi Nick, The purpose to extract the CSV files is to send them over to other systems, with some modifications done to columns in SSIS

Comment: Are you running all 17 DFTs in the package(s) at the same time? If you are, you may be running into buffer space issues. What values are the following DFT properties set to? DefaultBufferMaxRows, DefaultBufferMaxRows, EngineThreads

Comment: If you change all your Destinations to database tables instead of flat files, does it still take 2-3 days to finish?

Comment: yes, running all the 17 simultaneously. The DefaultMaxRows is set at 10000 and DefaultBufferSize is set to 10485760. I tried increasing the rows to 90000 and DefaultBufferSize to 100485760, but it didn't help either.                                              The memory on the machine is 24gb

Comment: no haven't tried exporting to database tables, as the exporting to CSV is a part of client request